# Create new element in xslt by appending the attribute value with it

Tags: xslt-2.0

```
<sec id="abg-c42-s1-1" disp-level="2">
<title>Introduction</title>
```

Problem : 
I have to check the disp-level attribute and replace < title> tag with < h>.
Example: If the value of disp-level is "1" then < title> tag is replaced by < h1>.
   If the value of disp-level is "3" then < title> tag is replaced by < h3> and so on.
Any solutions?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, write a template matching `sec[@disp-level]/title` that does that:

```
<xsl:template match="sec[@disp-level]/title">
  <xsl:element name="h{../@disp-level}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

As for most stylesheets, this approach works and easily allows further modular transformations of other elements or nodes if the stylesheet includes the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or in XSLT 3 the declaration `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`.

Comment: It is generating only "h" tag, not the values of disp-level.

Comment: @binodkumar, should be fixed now, consider to provide some sample input and wanted result data to test the next time.

Comment: ya it is fixed. thanks for the help. value is not extracted from sec tag. Thanx